# Repeat columns the number of times unique values in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I want to create a data.frame in R which has all the possible combinations of the following columns:-

1. Items: length around 2000
2. Weeks: length is 52 (Weeks in a Year)
3. Place: factor of length 3 i.e. ("Top", "Center", "Bottom")
4. Price: length around 2000 (each for each Item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not exactly clear to me what you would like to achieve. For example you can use `expand.grid()` to create a data.frame with all possible combinations:

```
items <- 1:200
weeks <- 1:52
place <- c("Top", "Center", "Bottom")
price <- 1:200

expand.grid(items, weeks, place, price)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Though, I have to change the Column Names manually later on.

Comment: To specify the column names: df <- data.frame(items = 1:200, ...) and then expand.grid(df)

Comment: Data Frame can't be formed brother since the Columns (variables) are not of same length. Anyways only a single line added can do the trick. There are no options in expand.grid() function for this.

Thanks for your help anyways

Comment: For vectors with different lengths you can use a list: lst <- list(items = 1:2, weeks = 1:5, place = c("T", "C"), price = 1:2) and then expand.grid(lst)